# Compare two folders mathematically using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare two folders in powershell and have the answer be either true or false. Is there anyway to make this happen? Right now I have:

```
Compare-Object -referenceobject $d1 -differenceobject $d2 -includeequal
```

But this shows me for every item.

My end game is to have one of the folder names change if they are equal (True) (to mark one OLD).

Answer (score 3):

You can negate the result and get a Boolean value. True if the objects are equal and False if they are not:

```
PS> $isEqual = compare (1..3) (1..3)
PS>  !$isEqual # change one of the folder names
True

PS> $isEqual = compare (1..3) (2..3)
PS>  !$isEqual
False
```

Comment: I tried to do this however it always came out as false even though all the sideindicators were equal. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Removing -includeequal, @Shay Levy solution works for me (with $d1 = Get-childItem $aRep)